# Passing tensorflow placeholders as function parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am passing two parameters to a my (loss) function in tensorflow which (I think) should be in form of placeholders because they change for different steps. I feed them on during training. 
My program outline is as follows. 
My question is do they take the values I feed them effectively?
I would appreciate if you can take a look at the following snippet and tell that I am doing it right?
I don't get any error or something by the way.

```
tetha1_placeholder, tetha2_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='tetha1plh'), tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='tetha2plh')
hyperparams = {'tetha1': tetha1_placeholder,'tetha2':tetha2_placeholder} 
[getting embeddings1,embeddings2, embeddings3 from my model]
loss = loss_function (embeddings1,embeddings1,embeddings3, hyperparams) 

with sess.as_default():

   while true:
        step = sess.run(global_step, feed_dict=None)
        t1, t2 = calculate_params(step)
        feed_dict = {tetha1_placeholder:t1, tetha2_placeholder:t2}            
        error=sess.run([loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)

def loss_function (embeddings1,embeddings2,embeddings3, hyperparams):
       pos_dist =hyperparams['tetha1'] * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(embeddings1, embeddings2)), 1)
       neg_dist = hyperparams['tetha2'] *tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(embeddings1, embeddings3)), 1)
       loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.add(pos_dist,neg_dist))
       return loss
```

Answer (score 0):

The program looks correct. When you call `sess.run([loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)`, the tensor `hyperparams['tetha1']` in `loss_function()` will have the value `t1`, and the tensor `hyperparams['tetha2']` in `loss_function()` will have the value `t2`.

As an aside, if `t1`  always has the same shape, I'd recommend passing that shape when you construct the `tf.placeholder()` for `tetha1_placeholder` (and similarly for `t2` and `tetha2_placeholder`).

Comment: Thanks @mrry
I didn't get the last part. t1 and t2 are just two scalar float numbers. You mean it would be better if I explicitly specify the shape of tetha1_placeholder as shape= (1) ?

Comment: Oh, if they're both scalars, you could define them as `tetha1_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[], name'tetha1plh')` (and similarly for the other placeholder). This can give you slightly better performance and error messages, depending on the exact computation.